# Delay a Listview or Image.network to avoid statusCode: 444

Tags: flutter, dart, httprequest

I have a ListView that is displaying some items in a Card. The Card has CachedNetworkImage that is loading images from links that I **scraped** earlier from a website into a list. My problem is - at least I think - the ListView has 50- 100 items, and the requests to load the images are being sent to the server too fast because out of the 50-100 images, sometimes 10-20 or 30 will load, and the rest will return HTTP request failed, statusCode: 444.
I am looking for a way to delay the requests, if only even for 200 milliseconds. I tried using FutureBuilder to delay, but when I print the time to monitor the speed of the request, they are all still being sent in a matter of a second.
Thanks

```
     FutureBuilder(
       future: Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
       builder:(c,s)=>
         ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 50,
            itemBuilder(context, index){
               return Card(
                  child: Row(
                     children: [
                        CachedNetworkImage(
                           imageUrl: imagesLink[index],
                        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        errorWidget: (context,url,error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
                      ),
                   ]
                ),
             );
          }
       )
     )
```

Comment: FYI it’s __scraped__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scrape__) not scrapped. ‘Scrapped’ means thrown away like rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

The api seems to be rate limiting your requests so you can't send them all at once. The problem with your approach is that it will only delay the `Listview.builder()` from displaying all your images. One approach would be to delay the showing of images one by one like this:

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: Future.delayed(
              Duration(milliseconds: 50 * index)), // Adjust this to fit api
          builder: (_, __) => Card(
            child: Row(children: [
                 CachedNetworkImage(
                       imageUrl: imagesLink[index],
                    placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    errorWidget: (context,url,error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
                  ),
            ]),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```